# How to delete objects from Realm using UITableView - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

What is the most common way (code structure) to delete objects from `Realm` through a `UITableView`?

The following code works fine to show data from `Realm` in a UITableView but not if I need to delete a row and update `Realm` since `Results` does not have a `remove` method.

Do I need to put my objects into a `List` and do the deleting through it? If this is the most common method I'm not so sure how to keep the 'List' and the `Results` from `Realm` in constant sync.

#### Model class

```
import RealmSwift

class Item:Object {
    dynamic var productName = ""
}
```

#### Main ViewController

```
let realm = try! Realm()
var items : Results<Item>?

var item:Item?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.items = realm.objects(Item.self)
}

func addNewItem(){
        item = Item(value: ["productName": productNameField.text!])
        // Save to Realm
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(item!)
        }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items!.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reusableCell", for: indexPath)
    let data = self.items![indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = data.productName
    return cell
}
```

#### Delete Rows

Standard method to delete rows from `UITableView` which of course does NOT work in this case since I'm using the default `Results` container from Realm.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete{
        items!.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
    }
}
```

Again, what is the most common way to delete objects from `Realm` through a `UITableView`?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some unwrapping and catching logic left out for brevity

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete{
        if let item = items?[indexPath.row] {
            try! realm.write {
                realm.delete(item)
            }
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see, the `Realm` class, oops. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Quick question, do you know how can I add/insert items at the beginning of the `Results` instead of at last (the default)? In other words I want to always insert items at [0] index. Something like... `try! realm.write {realm.insert(item!, at:0)}`, but of course `Realm` doesn't have a insert method.

Comment: This is a different question - I'd recommend asking in a separate thread.  SO admins frown on unrelated follow ons.  If you ask and tag me, I'd be happy to answer.

Comment: @ dmorrow - Here is the new question. Thanks a lot for your help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43471106/how-to-insert-items-at-0-index-to-the-realm-container

Answer (score 0):

You could also implement this block:

```
   if let item = items?[indexPath.row] {
                do {
                    try realm.write {
                        realm.delete(item)
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Error deleting item, \(error)")
                }
                tableView.reloadData()
            }
```