# How to insert items at 0 index to the Realm container

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Is there a way to insert new items at the 0 index to the `Realm` container? I don't see an insert method in the `Realm` class.

Do I need to use `List`s? If the answer is yes, how can I restructure the following code to be able to use `List`s and keep the List in constant sync with the `Realm` container. In other words I'm having a hard time coming up with a good way to keep the `Realm` container and the `List` with the same items when adding and removing.

In the following code new items are entered at the last index. How can I restructure it to be able to insert items at the 0 index?

#### Model class

```
import RealmSwift

class Item:Object {
    dynamic var productName = ""
}
```

#### Main ViewController

```
let realm = try! Realm()
var items : Results<Item>?

var item:Item?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.items = realm.objects(Item.self)
}

func addNewItem(){
        item = Item(value: ["productName": productNameField.text!])
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(item!)
        }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items!.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reusableCell", for: indexPath)
    let data = self.items![indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = data.productName
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete{
        if let item = items?[indexPath.row] {
            try! realm.write {
                realm.delete(item)
            }
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
        }
    }
}
```

#### Ideally this is what I would like to be able to do when inserting new items in the addNewItem() method...

```
    item = Item(value: ["productName": inputItem.text!])

    try! realm.write {
        realm.insert(item!, at:0) 
    }
```

Comment: It really depends what you want to sort on.  Important to remember Realm is a Database, not an Array, so it doesn't have an inherent concept of order - you have to define what 'order' means.

Comment: Make sense, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding a `sortedIndex` integer property that lets you manually control the ordering of objects is definitely one of the more popular ways to order objects in Realm, however it's quite inefficient. In order to insert an object at 0, you'll then need to loop through every other object and increment its ordering number by 1, meaning you'll end up needing to touch every object of that type in your database in order to do it.

The best practice for this sort of implementation is to create another `Object` model subclass that contains a `List` property, keep one instance of it in Realm, and to then add every object to that. `List` properties behave like normal arrays, so it's possible to very quick and efficient to arrange objects that way:

```
import RealmSwift

class ItemList: Object {
   let items = List<Item>()
}

class Item: Object {
    dynamic var productName = ""
}

let realm = try! Realm()

// Get the list object
let itemList = realm.objects(ItemList.self).first!

// Add a new item to it
let newItem = Item()
newItem.productName = "Item Name"

try! realm.write {
   itemList.items.insert(newItem, at: 0)
}
```

You can then use the `ItemList.items` object directly as the data source for your table view.

Comment: @ TiM - I like this method, thanks a lot for the good example. I wasn't sure how to use a `List` for something like this since in the documentation for the `List` at says...  `List is the container type in Realm used to define to-many relationships.` but I guess in a sense we are creating a `one-to-many` relation, just not using it for what they are traditionally used for. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome! You're welcome! Thanks! Yeah, it's the mechanism for when a parent object wants to manage a group of child objects. It's not a very orthodox way of doing it in other databases, but the object-based design means it matches very well. :) Good luck!

Comment: I get Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: @Parcker You can't specify nil if the property is non-optional. If you need more help, it might be better to open a new question. :)

Answer (score 4):

They're at least two ways to do this:

you can manually add priority as number in your class for.ex:

```
class Task: Item {
    dynamic var something = ""
    dynamic var priority = 0
}
```

add to realm:

```
//you can make priority 2,3,4 etc - 0 will be at the top
let task = Task(something: "Something", priority: 0)
```

and after retrieve objects:

```
var tasks: Results<Task>!
viewdidLoad(){
    let realm = try! Realm()
    tasks = realm.objects(Task.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "priority")
}
```

or you can make date like this:

```
class Task: Item {
    dynamic var something = ""
    dynamic var created = Date()

    override class func indexedPriority() -> [String]{
        return ["created"]
    }
}
```

add to realm:

```
let task = Task(something: "Something")
```

and after retrieve objects:

```
var tasks: Results<Task>!
viewdidLoad(){
    let realm = try! Realm()
    tasks = realm.objects(Task.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "created")
}
```

first one you must update yourself to assign priority, second one will be automatically updated

Comment: @ kam.voick - Interesting approaches, thanks. Two quick questions: 1st - In your `Task` class, shouldn't it be  `class Task: Object{}` instead of `class Task: Item{}`? 2nd - In your first example, does the priority number needs to be different/unique every time a new Task is entered? Thanks

Comment: priority doesn't need to be different, but if its not then the `sorted(byKeyPath:)` will return arbitrarily different results.  If you want it to always be the same, then sort by `something` after priority.  Reordering a whole set of objects means loading all of them into a Results array and then setting all of their new priorities.